# One-hot encoding for binary categorical variable

Tags: machine-learning, data-processing, one-hot-encoding, data-munging

I am trying to encode gender feature containing two values Male and Female. I created two one-hot features from main feature, is_male and is_female, containing boolean values. But while applying model, I realized they are complement to each other. Does this impact model performance as they seem to be correlated?

Comment: We don't do this in such cases; you should only create *one* variable, say `is_female`, which would take value 1 for females and 0 for males...

Answer (score 0):

One-hot encoding(creating separate columns for each value of column) should not be used with binary valued variables (MALE-FEMALE in your case).

Doing so causes **DUMMY VARIABLE TRAP**.